# Sorting bar chart in D3 not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a bar chart in D3, on selection of radio-button bar chart is shown and I want to sort by ascending or descending order. When clicking the button it is not sorting, so I don't know what wen t wrong but any help would be appreciated:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4s5m5je/2/ [Before adding sorting]

After i put sort button, bar chart doesn't show up and sort button too:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4s5m5je/3/

```
var sort_btn = document.getElementById('sort')
sort_btn.on("click", function(){
    var self = d3.select(this);
    var ascending = function(a,b){
            return a.value - b.value;
    };
    var descending = function(a,b){
            return b.value - a.value;
    }
    var state = +self.attr("state");
    var txt = "Sort data: ";
    if(state === 0){
            data.sort(ascending);
            state = 1;
            txt += "descending";
    } else if(state === 1){
            data.sort(descending);
            state = 0;
            txt += "ascending";
    }
    self.attr("state", state);
    self.html(txt);
```

Comment: You should get the button and save to the variable before trying to access it. Add the next line - `var sort_btn = document.getElementById('sort')` - before `sort_btn.on('click'`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ending bracket **});**

and move sort_btn implementation out of plot.call

For making the sorting works, you should fix more places.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j84Lq7u3/)

```
plot.call(chart, {
          data: data,
          axis:{
            x: xAxis,
            y: yAxis
          },
          gridlines: yGridlines
        }); 
var sort_btn = document.getElementById('sort')
sort_btn.on("click", function(){
var self = d3.select(this);
var ascending = function(a,b){
        return a.value - b.value;
};
var descending = function(a,b){
        return b.value - a.value;
}
var state = +self.attr("state");
var txt = "Sort data: ";
if(state === 0){
        data.sort(ascending);
        state = 1;
        txt += "descending";
} else if(state === 1){
        data.sort(descending);
        state = 0;
        txt += "ascending";
}
self.attr("state", state);
self.html(txt);

});
```

Comment: Can u give some idea as I am new to D3.

Comment: I didn't go through your logic, what i can think of sorting is every time you click sort button, you sort the data and redraw the chart. I'm not an expert in d3 either, maybe there is another better solution:)