# Need Help on Bar chart in D3 regarding selection of year and crimehead variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to D3. I was creating a bar chart but I am having some difficulty.
I am thinking of, first select the YEAR radio-button  after that secondly select the CRIMEHEAD and the bar chart would be shown.

IDEA: Say YEAR 2004 is selected, then again a CRIMEHEAD is selected, then data of that particular YEAR[2004] of the selected CRIMEHEAD should only be taken and bar chart would be seen.

Any kind of help would be appreciated and looking forward.

http://jsfiddle.net/zw98b3pv/

```
// YEAR radio button
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("input:radio[name=year]").click(function() {

    value = $(this).val();

    $(".chart").empty();
```

// CRIMEHEAD radio button

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var value="Total";

$("input:radio[name=crime]").click(function() {

    value = $(this).val();

    $(".chart").empty();
```

But in above link, all the datas of that particular CRIMEHEAD of all years are shown.

If CRIMEHEAD is selected first then a message would pop up telling select the YEAR first.

here is without YEAR radio-button
http://jsfiddle.net/zw98b3pv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would try is mapping the correct data.

Instead of

```
data: data,
```

put

```
data: $.map(data, function(o,i){        
  if (o.YEAR == $("input:radio[name=year]").val())
      return o;
  }),
```

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/zw98b3pv/2/

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to add a condition for taking the selected value, should be:

```
if (o.YEAR == $("input:radio[name=year]:checked").val())
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/zw98b3pv/6/

Comment: Thank you very much. But it comes only for year 2001.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Could u please check about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803811/sorting-bar-chart-in-d3-not-working

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. If an answer was helpful for you please accept it by clicking the "V" next to the answer.

Comment: Thank for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/14/  Could you help me with this one, I want to get data for pie chart on mouse hovering to states map.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847482/need-help-on-pie-chart-transition-on-mouse-hover-of-a-state-of-the-map-according